# How to find secret-rotation executor in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I am setting up Keycloak Client Secret Rotation Policy using their [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_proc-secret-rotation). However, I couldn't find `secret-rotation` option in the executor. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of 23.0.1 this feature is Disabled by default.  You have to enable it at startup using the --features option.  According to the manual, this feature is in development and should be used experimentally.  See this screen grab:
[KeyCloak Server Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7Rw.png)

Run the `kc start --help` to see the list of features you can enable at startup.